Docker push incorrectly resolves when pushing to a private Gitlab Repository
I am trying to setup a private repository using Gitlab container repositories, my Gitlab instance is currently setup on an LXC container with an NGINX reverse proxy routing git subdomain (as well as now the repository subdomain) to the Gitlab container. After I set up the repository per https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html I can login to my Docker repository using my Gitlab credentials using docker login repository.git.example.com, however pushing an image to it (manually for now) results in a  dial tcp <CLIENT IP>:80: i/o timeout error following retries, interestingly the CLIENT IP it's trying to upload to is actually my public facing IP rather than that of my Gitlab server which is puzzling, this behavior occurs on a different computer as well.
More interestingly, I am able to push the image locally on the host using docker push localhost:5090 (5090 being the port I'm exposing mapping to port 5000 on Gitlab instance), I can then pull that image on my local machine using the domain without issues so the issue only occurs on push commands specifically.
I have also attempted to use a VPN to see if it will update the IP it's trying to upload to or if it will keep trying my home IP, and it does indeed update the IP to that of the VPN.
I have tried playing around with gitlab.rb and nginx config settings but to no avail
Also worth noting that the reverse proxy works perfect otherwise, my Gitlab instance is operating perfectly well for git using a similar setup
The port mappings I have configured are such that port 5000 on Gitlab container maps to port 5090 on host, which is then reverse proxied to by a locally running NGINX instance.
Relevant configs attached:
gitlab.rb:
################################################################################
## Container Registry settings
##! Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html
################################################################################

registry_external_url 'https://registry.git.example.com'

### Settings used by GitLab application
gitlab_rails['registry_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['registry_host'] = "localhost"
gitlab_rails['registry_port'] = "5050"
gitlab_rails['registry_path'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/registry"

###! **Do not change the following 3 settings unless you know what you are
###!   doing**
gitlab_rails['registry_api_url'] = "http://localhost:5000"

### Settings used by Registry application
registry['enable'] = true
registry['username'] = "registry"
registry['group'] = "registry"
registry['dir'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/registry"
registry['registry_http_addr'] = "localhost:5000"
registry['log_level'] = "info"
registry['log_formatter'] = "text"
registry['health_storagedriver_enabled'] = true
registry['storage_delete_enabled'] = true
registry['validation_enabled'] = false
registry['autoredirect'] = false
registry['compatibility_schema1_enabled'] = false
...
registry_nginx['enable'] = false
registry_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true

registry_nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
 "Host" => "$http_host",
 "X-Real-IP" => "$remote_addr",
 "X-Forwarded-For" => "$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
 "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
 "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on"
}

# When the registry is automatically enabled using the same domain as `external_url`,
# it listens on this port
registry_nginx['listen_port'] = 5050
registry_nginx['listen_https'] = false


registry.nginx.conf
server {
    server_name registry.git.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5090;
        proxy_read_timeout               900;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
        # client_max_body_size 250m;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.git.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/registry.git.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

docker push ... output
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [registry.git.example.com/test/project]
72d010a50a10: Pushing [==================================================>]   48.9MB/48.9MB
6d7475ac832d: Retrying in 1 second 
2b68589d6edf: Retrying in 1 second 
10f93ebb71ca: Retrying in 1 second 
ce366fe0c2d0: Pushing [==================================================>]  3.072kB
1199d55552de: Waiting 
7f921f0f25f6: Waiting 
9fa56fd54db1: Waiting 
b4362cb4980f: Waiting 
25fd91011cd8: Waiting 
31cb9c18c427: Waiting 
5c792cb82821: Waiting 
d1281f9883d7: Waiting 
5756a972e734: Waiting 
67e13e951fda: Waiting 
32148f9f6c5a: Waiting 
dial tcp <CLIENT IP>:80: i/o timeout


Gitlab logs:
2024-07-29_03:50:10.77658 time="2024-07-29T03:50:10.776Z" level=info msg="router info" config_http_addr="localhost:5000" config_http_host= config_http_net= config_http_prefix= config_http_relative_urls=false correlation_id=01J3Y9RA2RVMR8ADTV9XTW1HJB go_version=go1.20.12 method=GET path=/v2/ root_repo= router=gorilla/mux version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:10.77687 {"content_type":"application/json","correlation_id":"01J3Y9RA2RVMR8ADTV9XTW1HJB","duration_ms":0,"host":"registry.git.example.com","level":"info","method":"GET","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.0","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:51574","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":401,"system":"http","time":"2024-07-29T03:50:10.776Z","ttfb_ms":0,"uri":"/v2/","user_agent":"docker/24.0.5 go/go1.20.3 git-commit/24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 kernel/6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.5 \\(linux\\))","written_bytes":87}
2024-07-29_03:50:29.68593 time="2024-07-29T03:50:29.685Z" level=info msg="router info" config_http_addr="localhost:5000" config_http_host= config_http_net= config_http_prefix= config_http_relative_urls=false correlation_id=01J3Y9RWHNXP0EQBNKYZ3B8JQT go_version=go1.20.12 method=HEAD path="/v2/test/project/blobs/sha256:3bdbfec22900c781414625092df5d4a57000133308b3392062e2080c37c27d5b" root_repo=test router=gorilla/mux vars_digest="sha256:3bdbfec22900c781414625092df5d4a57000133308b3392062e2080c37c27d5b" vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:29.68937 time="2024-07-29T03:50:29.689Z" level=info msg="authorized request" auth_project_paths="[test/project]" auth_user_name=sviridovt auth_user_type=gitlab_or_ldap correlation_id=01J3Y9RWHNXP0EQBNKYZ3B8JQT go_version=go1.20.12 root_repo=test vars_digest="sha256:3bdbfec22900c781414625092df5d4a57000133308b3392062e2080c37c27d5b" vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:29.68978 {"content_type":"application/json","correlation_id":"01J3Y9RWHNXP0EQBNKYZ3B8JQT","duration_ms":4,"host":"registry.git.example.com","level":"info","method":"HEAD","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.0","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:54252","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":404,"system":"http","time":"2024-07-29T03:50:29.689Z","ttfb_ms":4,"uri":"/v2/test/project/blobs/sha256:3bdbfec22900c781414625092df5d4a57000133308b3392062e2080c37c27d5b","user_agent":"docker/24.0.5 go/go1.20.3 git-commit/24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 kernel/6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.5 \\(linux\\))","written_bytes":157}
2024-07-29_03:50:29.89622 time="2024-07-29T03:50:29.896Z" level=info msg="router info" config_http_addr="localhost:5000" config_http_host= config_http_net= config_http_prefix= config_http_relative_urls=false correlation_id=01J3Y9RWR7CWEGRXJW73WTM1ZN go_version=go1.20.12 method=POST path=/v2/test/project/blobs/uploads/ root_repo=test router=gorilla/mux vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:29.89752 time="2024-07-29T03:50:29.897Z" level=info msg="authorized request" auth_project_paths="[test/project]" auth_user_name=sviridovt auth_user_type=gitlab_or_ldap correlation_id=01J3Y9RWR7CWEGRXJW73WTM1ZN go_version=go1.20.12 root_repo=test vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:29.92582 {"content_type":"","correlation_id":"01J3Y9RWR7CWEGRXJW73WTM1ZN","duration_ms":29,"host":"registry.git.example.com","level":"info","method":"POST","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.0","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:54266","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":202,"system":"http","time":"2024-07-29T03:50:29.925Z","ttfb_ms":29,"uri":"/v2/test/project/blobs/uploads/","user_agent":"docker/24.0.5 go/go1.20.3 git-commit/24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 kernel/6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.5 \\(linux\\))","written_bytes":0}
2024-07-29_03:50:30.10935 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.109Z" level=info msg="router info" config_http_addr="localhost:5000" config_http_host= config_http_net= config_http_prefix= config_http_relative_urls=false correlation_id=01J3Y9RWYWEH7230ERQY2S26G9 go_version=go1.20.12 method=HEAD path="/v2/test/project/blobs/sha256:f2bf536a1e4f91a97ae0ac1e23dded074d073a5785211ff9acedee8766601287" root_repo=test router=gorilla/mux vars_digest="sha256:f2bf536a1e4f91a97ae0ac1e23dded074d073a5785211ff9acedee8766601287" vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.11244 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.112Z" level=info msg="authorized request" auth_project_paths="[test/project]" auth_user_name=sviridovt auth_user_type=gitlab_or_ldap correlation_id=01J3Y9RWYWEH7230ERQY2S26G9 go_version=go1.20.12 root_repo=test vars_digest="sha256:f2bf536a1e4f91a97ae0ac1e23dded074d073a5785211ff9acedee8766601287" vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.11282 {"content_type":"application/json","correlation_id":"01J3Y9RWYWEH7230ERQY2S26G9","duration_ms":3,"host":"registry.git.example.com","level":"info","method":"HEAD","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.0","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:54278","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":404,"system":"http","time":"2024-07-29T03:50:30.112Z","ttfb_ms":3,"uri":"/v2/test/project/blobs/sha256:f2bf536a1e4f91a97ae0ac1e23dded074d073a5785211ff9acedee8766601287","user_agent":"docker/24.0.5 go/go1.20.3 git-commit/24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 kernel/6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.5 \\(linux\\))","written_bytes":157}
2024-07-29_03:50:30.11923 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.119Z" level=info msg="router info" config_http_addr="localhost:5000" config_http_host= config_http_net= config_http_prefix= config_http_relative_urls=false correlation_id=01J3Y9RWZ6J9FJZ6S9KR44KMJ3 go_version=go1.20.12 method=POST path=/v2/test/project/blobs/uploads/ root_repo=test router=gorilla/mux vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.12241 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.122Z" level=info msg="authorized request" auth_project_paths="[test/project]" auth_user_name=sviridovt auth_user_type=gitlab_or_ldap correlation_id=01J3Y9RWZ6J9FJZ6S9KR44KMJ3 go_version=go1.20.12 root_repo=test vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.12273 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.122Z" level=info msg="router info" config_http_addr="localhost:5000" config_http_host= config_http_net= config_http_prefix= config_http_relative_urls=false correlation_id=01J3Y9RWZAVEDW2NSJB4T79YEJ go_version=go1.20.12 method=HEAD path="/v2/test/project/blobs/sha256:83396b6ad4ccd49973244f1cd4f4e6b4c47a0c0b9672cbf789c4ed40b5bab2e6" root_repo=test router=gorilla/mux vars_digest="sha256:83396b6ad4ccd49973244f1cd4f4e6b4c47a0c0b9672cbf789c4ed40b5bab2e6" vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.12603 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.125Z" level=info msg="authorized request" auth_project_paths="[test/project]" auth_user_name=sviridovt auth_user_type=gitlab_or_ldap correlation_id=01J3Y9RWZAVEDW2NSJB4T79YEJ go_version=go1.20.12 root_repo=test vars_digest="sha256:83396b6ad4ccd49973244f1cd4f4e6b4c47a0c0b9672cbf789c4ed40b5bab2e6" vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.12639 {"content_type":"application/json","correlation_id":"01J3Y9RWZAVEDW2NSJB4T79YEJ","duration_ms":4,"host":"registry.git.example.com","level":"info","method":"HEAD","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.0","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:54296","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":404,"system":"http","time":"2024-07-29T03:50:30.126Z","ttfb_ms":3,"uri":"/v2/test/project/blobs/sha256:83396b6ad4ccd49973244f1cd4f4e6b4c47a0c0b9672cbf789c4ed40b5bab2e6","user_agent":"docker/24.0.5 go/go1.20.3 git-commit/24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 kernel/6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.5 \\(linux\\))","written_bytes":157}
2024-07-29_03:50:30.14091 {"content_type":"","correlation_id":"01J3Y9RWZ6J9FJZ6S9KR44KMJ3","duration_ms":22,"host":"registry.git.example.com","level":"info","method":"POST","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.0","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:54290","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":202,"system":"http","time":"2024-07-29T03:50:30.140Z","ttfb_ms":22,"uri":"/v2/test/project/blobs/uploads/","user_agent":"docker/24.0.5 go/go1.20.3 git-commit/24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 kernel/6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.5 \\(linux\\))","written_bytes":0}
2024-07-29_03:50:30.31554 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.315Z" level=info msg="router info" config_http_addr="localhost:5000" config_http_host= config_http_net= config_http_prefix= config_http_relative_urls=false correlation_id=01J3Y9RX5BEXRDX940H1FWWYJ3 go_version=go1.20.12 method=POST path=/v2/test/project/blobs/uploads/ root_repo=test router=gorilla/mux vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.31857 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.318Z" level=info msg="authorized request" auth_project_paths="[test/project]" auth_user_name=sviridovt auth_user_type=gitlab_or_ldap correlation_id=01J3Y9RX5BEXRDX940H1FWWYJ3 go_version=go1.20.12 root_repo=test vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.32403 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.323Z" level=info msg="router info" config_http_addr="localhost:5000" config_http_host= config_http_net= config_http_prefix= config_http_relative_urls=false correlation_id=01J3Y9RX5KJKW72TC3PM0Q2ACF go_version=go1.20.12 method=POST path=/v2/test/project/blobs/uploads/ root_repo=test router=gorilla/mux vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.32695 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.326Z" level=info msg="authorized request" auth_project_paths="[test/project]" auth_user_name=sviridovt auth_user_type=gitlab_or_ldap correlation_id=01J3Y9RX5KJKW72TC3PM0Q2ACF go_version=go1.20.12 root_repo=test vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.35037 {"content_type":"","correlation_id":"01J3Y9RX5BEXRDX940H1FWWYJ3","duration_ms":35,"host":"registry.git.example.com","level":"info","method":"POST","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.0","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:54308","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":202,"system":"http","time":"2024-07-29T03:50:30.350Z","ttfb_ms":35,"uri":"/v2/test/project/blobs/uploads/","user_agent":"docker/24.0.5 go/go1.20.3 git-commit/24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 kernel/6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.5 \\(linux\\))","written_bytes":0}
2024-07-29_03:50:30.35492 {"content_type":"","correlation_id":"01J3Y9RX5KJKW72TC3PM0Q2ACF","duration_ms":31,"host":"registry.git.example.com","level":"info","method":"POST","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.0","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:54324","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":202,"system":"http","time":"2024-07-29T03:50:30.354Z","ttfb_ms":31,"uri":"/v2/test/project/blobs/uploads/","user_agent":"docker/24.0.5 go/go1.20.3 git-commit/24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 kernel/6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.5 \\(linux\\))","written_bytes":0}
2024-07-29_03:50:30.53036 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.530Z" level=info msg="router info" config_http_addr="localhost:5000" config_http_host= config_http_net= config_http_prefix= config_http_relative_urls=false correlation_id=01J3Y9RXC1Q0XWKNQNGP18VZKX go_version=go1.20.12 method=POST path=/v2/test/project/blobs/uploads/ root_repo=test router=gorilla/mux vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.53371 time="2024-07-29T03:50:30.533Z" level=info msg="authorized request" auth_project_paths="[test/project]" auth_user_name=sviridovt auth_user_type=gitlab_or_ldap correlation_id=01J3Y9RXC1Q0XWKNQNGP18VZKX go_version=go1.20.12 root_repo=test vars_name=test/project version=v3.88.0-gitlab
2024-07-29_03:50:30.55577 {"content_type":"","correlation_id":"01J3Y9RXC1Q0XWKNQNGP18VZKX","duration_ms":25,"host":"registry.git.example.com","level":"info","method":"POST","msg":"access","proto":"HTTP/1.0","referrer":"","remote_addr":"127.0.0.1:54340","remote_ip":"127.0.0.1","status":202,"system":"http","time":"2024-07-29T03:50:30.555Z","ttfb_ms":25,"uri":"/v2/test/project/blobs/uploads/","user_agent":"docker/24.0.5 go/go1.20.3 git-commit/24.0.5-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 kernel/6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/24.0.5 \\(linux\\))","written_bytes":0}


curl registry:
curl -i https://registry.git.example.com/v2/
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 30 Jul 2024 09:49:58 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 87
Connection: keep-alive
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version: registry/2.0
Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://git.example.com/jwt/auth",service="container_registry"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}

I have now been at this for a couple of days so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Please update the question with the output of curl -i https://registry.git.example.com/v2/

@BMitch Updated

I should also note that pinging the registry domain does resolve to the correct IP for the server

Looking at this again, I see the issue is on the blob push (not the auth). The registry or proxy is going to be giving the wrong Location header in the post or patch request.

Yeah, I figured it was somehow returning the wrong location (presumably somewhere in the reverse proxy it looks like location gets changed to origin IP) but not too sure how to debug that

You can narrow it down by running a push directly to the registry, without the proxy. Most likely the proxy isn't touching that header and the registry is misconfigured (you could also spin up a simple registry:2 instance to verify that).
